# Shotwell & Nautilus not emailing pictures

Tags: nautilus, email, shotwell

When I want to email pictures, I open Shotwell and select the ones that I want. I right-click and use the "send to" to  have them sent as an email, but nothing is sent. I have evolution set up with my email.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the Nautilus send-to feature. There's a packaging bug in certain version of Ubuntu (and apparently Debian as well, or so I'm told) that prevents your e-mail client from appearing in the drop down list.

There's a bug report on this here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-sendto/+bug/765847

As mentioned in that ticket, the solution for this is here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10753508&postcount=5